# building android kernel 3.4

Tags: android, android-kernel

I am facing issues in building the android kernel. I tried the following steps from the following link ( http://source.android.com/source/building-kernels.html )

**I donot have the AOSP. I am just trying to compile the kernel**

```
Source: git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/goldfish.git
```

I placed the tool chain in the following directory

```
/home/chid/goldfish/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/x86/i686-linux-android-4.6/bin
```

I set the path as follows

```
export PATH=$(pwd)/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/x86/i686-linux-android-4.6/bin:$PATH
pwd: /home/chid/goldfish
```

set the environment variables as follows.

```
export ARCH=x86
export SUBARCH=x86
export CROSS_COMPILE=i686-linux-android-
```

setup the config file as

```
make arch=x86 goldfish_defconfig
```

gave make as follows.

```
make -j6
```

But it tells me a "cannot find" error.

Error:
/home/chid/goldfish/scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 25: /home/chid/goldfish/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/x86/i686-linux-android-4.6/bin/i686-linux-android-gcc: **No such file or directory**

Can you tell me what I am missing? I ensured that the above mentioned file is present and the path is set correctly. Is there something else I need to take care of?

Comment: Try invoking that gcc directly from the command line.  How did you install it?  Did you move it through a non-unix filesystem or do anything that could have stripped the execute bit?

Answer (score 0):

You got the toolchain as the following?

```
$ git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/x86/i686-linux-android-4.6
```

Have you tried to launch gcc directly?

```
$ /home/chid/goldfish/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/x86/i686-linux-android-4.6/bin/i686-linux-android-gcc
```

How about ldd?

```
$ ldd /home/chid/goldfish/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/x86/i686-linux-android-4.6/bin/i686-linux-android-gcc
```

In vagrant precise32 Ubuntu image, no problems at all.

```
$ ldd i686-linux-android-4.6/bin/i686-linux-android-gcc
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb77c7000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb7619000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb77c8000)

$ i686-linux-android-4.6/bin/i686-linux-android-gcc
i686-linux-android-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

$ sh goldfish/scripts/gcc-version.sh i686-linux-android-4.6/bin/i686-linux-android-gcc
0406
```

You might need to have another Linux environment to execute gcc.